# Creating Video player which support IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with creating a video player in my webpage. I have a list of video title and one video player using object tage.

My purpose: when i click on video title, it will load the video and play according to video's file.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: post code, error messages, browser/OS versions, need much more info.

Answer (score 0):

**[Try the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/v3xa5/)**

```
<a href="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg">Test video</a><br>
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Pentagon_News_Sample.ogg">Pentagon</a><br>
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Xacti-AC8EX-Sample_video-001.ogg/Xacti-AC8EX-Sample_video-001.ogg.480p.webm">Cat Giraffe</a><br>

<video id="player" src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>​​​​​​​​​​​​​

<script type="text/javascript">
​$(function(e) {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var video_file = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#player').attr('src', video_file)[0].play();
    });        
});​
</script>
```